# How do I know when does a type signature is total or not?

Tags: functional-programming, idris, dependent-type

```
module Print

data Format : Type where
  Num : Format -> Format
  Str : Format -> Format
  Lit : String -> Format -> Format
  End : Format

PrintfType : Format -> Type
PrintfType (Num f)   = (i : Int) -> PrintfType f
PrintfType (Str f)   = (s : String) -> PrintfType f
PrintfType (Lit _ f) = PrintfType f
PrintfType End       = String

printfFmt : (fmt : Format) -> (acc : String) -> PrintfType fmt
printfFmt (Num f) acc   = \i => printfFmt f  (acc ++ show i)
printfFmt (Str f) acc   = \s => printfFmt f (acc ++ s)
printfFmt (Lit s f) acc = printfFmt f (acc ++ s)
printfFmt End acc       = acc

printf : (fmt : Format) -> PrintfType fmt
printf fmt = printfFmt fmt ""

-- Is this function possible?
printLst : {fmt : Format} -> List Format -> String -> PrintfType fmt
printLst [] x = ?printLst_rhs_1
printLst (y :: xs) x = let now = printfFmt y ""
                       in printLst xs ?now 

-- printLst [Str End, Num End] "" ["a", 1]
-- # "a1"
```

Extending the example from the paper **Quantitative Type Theory in Practice**, Section 2.3.1 Computing Type.

Ref: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.00480.pdf

If I want to implement a `printLst` function that works with List of Format.

Update: the `printLst` function will take a list of format and a list of input that follows the Format specified in the list of format.

```
printLst [Str End, Num End] "" ["a", 1]
# output: "a1"
```

How can I know whether this type signature is total or not?

Comment: by "possible to implement", do you mean "can be made `total`"?

Comment: and what would your `printf` do with this list of `Format`?

Comment: updated more info of the question

Comment: i think, though I'm not sure, that everything at type level has to be total else the compiler can't do its job